# How to run checkbox widget using Popup in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, widget, popup

Newbie kivy user here. I have created 2 Kivy apps, and each works individually but I can't integrate one to the other. I am trying to run the `CheckBoxesApp` in `MyApp` using Popup(`onButtonPress3`). When I ran my code, I got the error "`WidgetException: add_widget() can be used only with instances of the Widget class.`" Might be related to the fact that CheckBoxesApp uses App while MyApp uses MDApp? Any help appreciated >>

main.py

```
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.1')
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup


FruitsSellected = []


class Checkboxes(Widget):

  def checkboxes_click(self, instance, value, text):
    if value:
      print(f"Select {text}")
      self.myvar = FruitsSellected
      #Close
      if text == 'FINISH':
        print(FruitsSellected)
        self.save()
        App.get_running_app().stop()
        return FruitsSellected

      FruitsSellected.append(str(text))

    else:
      print(f"UnSelect {text}")
      FruitsSellected.remove(str(text))

  def save(self):
    with open("allergenlist.txt", "w") as fobj:
      fobj.write(str(self.myvar))




class CheckBoxesApp(App):
  def build(self):
    return Checkboxes()


class MyApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        # Define a grid layout for this App
        self.layout = GridLayout(cols=1, padding=10)

        # Don't worry about this button, just a place holder
        self.button = Button(text="TAKE PICTURE")
        self.layout.add_widget(self.button)
        # Add a button
        self.button2 = Button(text="SELECT")
        self.layout.add_widget(self.button2)        # Add a button

        # Attach a callback for the button press event
        self.button.bind(on_press=self.onButtonPress)
        self.button2.bind(on_press=self.onButtonPress3)

        return self.layout

    #Place Holder don't worry about this either
    def onButtonPress(self, button):

        layout = GridLayout(cols=1, padding=10)

        popupLabel = Label(text="TAKE PICTURE")
        closeButton = Button(text="Close the pop-up")

        layout.add_widget(popupLabel)
        layout.add_widget(closeButton)

        # Instantiate the modal popup and display
        popup = Popup(title='TAKE PICTURE',
                      content=layout)
        popup.open()

        # Attach close button press
        closeButton.bind(on_press=popup.dismiss)



    def onButtonPress3(self, button):


        layout = CheckBoxesApp()
        popup3 = Popup(title='SELECT', content=layout)
        popup3.open()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Checkboxes.kv

```
<Checkboxes>

  # Create Box Layout
  BoxLayout:
    # set orientation and size
    orientation: "vertical"
    size: root.width, root.height

    # Creating label


    # create Grid Layout
    GridLayout:
      # Set number of column
      cols:4

      # create checkboxes
      Label:
        text: "Apple"

      CheckBox:
        # When check box selected, it will call checkboxes_click() method
        on_active: root.checkboxes_click(self, self.active, "Apple")

      Label:
        text: "Bannana"

      CheckBox:
        on_active: root.checkboxes_click(self, self.active, "Bannana")

      Label:
        text: "Orange"

      CheckBox:
        on_active: root.checkboxes_click(self, self.active, "Orange")

      Label:
        text: "Grape"

      CheckBox:
        on_active: root.checkboxes_click(self, self.active, "Grape")

      Label:
        text: "Melon"

      CheckBox:
        on_active: root.checkboxes_click(self, self.active, "Melon")

      Label:
        text: "Peach"

      CheckBox:
        on_active: root.checkboxes_click(self, self.active, "Peach")

      Label:
        text: "Pineapple"

      CheckBox:
        on_active: root.checkboxes_click(self, self.active, "Pineapple")

      Label:
        text: "FINISH"

      CheckBox:
        on_active: root.checkboxes_click(self, self.active, "FINISH")
```

Answer (score 0):

The `content` of a `Popup` must be a `Widget`, but an `App` is not a `Widget`, so your code:

```
def onButtonPress3(self, button):
    layout = CheckBoxesApp()
    popup3 = Popup(title='SELECT', content=layout)
    popup3.open()
```

will fail.

I suggest changing that code to:

```
def onButtonPress3(self, button):
    # layout = CheckBoxesApp()
    layout = Checkboxes()
    popup3 = Popup(title='SELECT', content=layout)
    popup3.open()
```

Of course, you must load the `Checkboxes.kv` file explicitly for this to work.

Comment: bro thank you so much, I was stuck on this problem for ages